# Ionic harware back button not working (Android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, back

I have an app with a side menu but the hardware back button doesn't on the pages of the side menu.

my side menu has the following structure:

(side menu list)

- favorites
  lists of favorite items
- saved

  list of saved items

and the back button looks like this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">          
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

but how do i get the hardware back button to work on the Android phone

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?